# Who loves every being / every human being

Tags: exam-questions, error

Is the following sentence grammatically correct ?

> Jessica is a spiritually centred person who loves every being she comes in contact with.

Is it correct to say *being* instead of *human being* ?

Comment: Animals are usually considered beings too, so it's correct, but it means something different. I can say "John likes blue cars" or "John likes cars", but they do not mean exactly the same.

Comment: [*being*](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/being): "3. *countable noun* - You can refer to any real or imaginary creature as a being. *People expect a horse to perform like a car, with no thought for its feelings as a living being. ...beings from outer space*."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use being instead of human being, but human being is more common than being.  The use of being is ambiguous; it may mean a human being or a living creature.

,